# Character Position Moved after Animation assigned

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My character position is moved after an animation is assigned.

The character `GameObject` is assigned with `Animation`, `RigidBody`, `Capsule Collider` and a `C# Script` Component.

The C# Script (animation part) is as follow:

```
public class MyCharacter : MonoBehaviour {
        // Animations
    public AnimationClip idleAnimation;
    public AnimationClip slideAnimation;
    public AnimationClip runAnimation;
    public AnimationClip jumpPoseAnimation;
    private Animation charAnimation;

    enum CharacterState {
        Idle = 0,
        Running = 1,
        Sliding = 2,
        Jumping = 3,
    }

    private CharacterState charState;

    void Start () {
        charState = CharacterState.Running;
        charAnimation = gameObject.GetComponent<Animation>();
        if(!charAnimation) {
            Debug.Log("No Animation Component.");
        } else {
            AnimationEvent syncRunEvent = new AnimationEvent();
            syncRunEvent.time = runAnimation.length;
            syncRunEvent.functionName = "SyncRunAnimation";
            runAnimation.AddEvent(syncRunEvent);
        }
    }

        void Update () {
                // Animations
        if(charAnimation) {
            if(charState == CharacterState.Jumping) {
                charAnimation.CrossFade(jumpPoseAnimation.name);
            } else if(charState == CharacterState.Sliding) {
                charAnimation.CrossFade(slideAnimation.name);
            } else {
                charAnimation.CrossFade(runAnimation.name);
            }
        }
    }

        void SyncRunAnimation() {
        Debug.Log("Sync Run");
        transform.position += new Vector3(0, 3, 0);
    }
}
```

Before assigning the animation, the character is standing in the ground at position `(0, 0.6, 0)`. After assigning, the character submerges INTO the ground, stuck; position changed to `(0, -0.75, -0.55)`, which is the position of Imported animation. How can I control the animation position ?

Note: I tried to use `SyncEvent` to move up ( increase Y axis ), but it does NO effect at all.

---

This only happens when Animation is set to **Legacy**. If I set the animation to **Generic**, it has no problem, but Console issues errors :

> The AnimationClip 'run' used by the Animation component 'MyCharacter' must be marked as Legacy.

and the animation could not be played. How can I make it work with Generic animation / correct position with Legacy animation ?

Comment: What is the structure of your gameobject? Does it have any children?

Comment: the character `GameObject` is an imported FBX 3D model with animations. 3 children: 2 lights & 1 camera. The character has also Capsule collider & Rigid Body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the the position keyframes of FBX animations affect the position. After removed the Properties in Animation panel, the issue is gone.

[image: Remove this Properties]

*However, the keyframes sometimes re-appear.*

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it's best to make your 3D model a child object of some parent gameobject. The parent gameobject has the controller scripts and whatnot. I don't know if that will fix the issue. I'm guessing that the animation is changing the position and location of the model, which is affecting the gameobject's transform. If you make it a child of some other gameobject, that might not happen.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to handle the problem. First you enable 'Apply Root Motion' in Animator panel. In this case the rotation and position data will be additive not absolute. But it might be happen that the original rotation or position will be loss after repeating your animation. In this case you can make an empty gameObject. Position it to your gameObject (into it's origin) what is animated. After this put your animated gameObject into the empty gameObject (in Hierachy view)